# How find this $n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_{n}-(n-2)a_{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Suppose
>   $$n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_{n}-(n-2)a_{n-1}$$
>   for every postive integers $n\ge 1$,Give that $a_{0}=1,a_{1}=2$

find the $a_{n}$

**My try:**

> $$a_{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2!},a_{3}=\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{3!},\cdots$$
>   so I guess 
>   $$a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n!}(n\ge 2)$$
>   **and we easy use the Mathematical induction prove it.**

**My question:**

**This problem have without mathematical induction to solve it?**

and following is my idea:

> let $n(n+1)a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}$
>   so
>   $$b_{n+1}=b_{n}-\dfrac{b_{n-1}}{n-1},n\ge 2$$
>   then I can't,Thank you for your help!

This problem from http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1290603&sid=5c95d4057706d4a61097b007952afb70#p1290603

Comment: The sequence itself is defined by induction, so any solution must involve induction in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_n = na_n -a_{n-1}$.  Then, rearranging:

$$n[(n+1)a_{n+1}-(n-1)a_n] = -(n-2)a_{n-1}$$

$$n[(n+1)a_{n+1}-a_n - (n-2)a_n] = -(n-2)a_{n-1}$$

$$nc_{n+1} - n(n-2)a_n = -(n-2)a_{n-1}$$

$$nc_{n+1} = (n-2)(na_n - a_{n-1})$$

$$c_{n+1} = (1-2/n)\cdot c_n$$

Plugging in $n=2$, we have $c_3=0$, and it follows that $c_4=0$, $c_5=0$, etc.  So, for $n\geq 3$, $c_n=0$ and $na_n = a_{n-1}$.

We have to calculate one value "by hand": plugging in $n=1$ into the original equation gives $a_2=1/2$.

Then, for $n\geq 2$, we calculate: $a_n = 1/n \cdot a_{n-1} = 1/n \cdot 1/(n-1) \cdot \ldots  \cdot a_2 = 1/n!$.

Comment: +1, especially for taking care of the inconvenience that the prefactor $1-2/n$ is zero for some $n$.

Comment: @Did Hmm, it seems more like a convenience that I didn't take advantage of.  I confused the problem with the work below, and assumed that $a_2=1/2$, $a_3=1/3$ were initial conditions.  In fact, you only need $a_2$, and technically, you have to deduce it from the problem somehow.  Fixed.