# How prove this sequence $a_{n}$ is $a_{n}=2n+1$ without mathematical induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let  sequence  $a_{1}=3$ and $$a_{n+1}=a^2_{n}-2na_{n}+2,n\ge 1$$
>
> Find the $a_{n}$

My idea: 
since
$$a_{2}=9-6+2=5,a_{3}=a^2_{2}-4a_{2}+2=25-20+2=7,a_{4}=a^2_{3}-6a_{3}+2=49-42+2=9$$
so I inductive
$$a_{n}=2n+1$$
and it is easy use Mathematical induction to prove it

since
$$a_{n+1}=(2n+1)^2-2n\cdot (2n+1)+2=2(n+1)+1$$

My Question,This sequence have without mathematical induction methods?

such as this two  post. At first I thought to can't find other ways, but finally surprised someone gives three different methods:

[How find this $n(n+1)a_{n+1}=n(n-1)a_{n}-(n-2)a_{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549947/how-find-this-nn1a-n1-nn-1a-n-n-2a-n-1)

,[How find $a_{n}$ if the sequence $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+(2n-1)^2a_{n-2},n\ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919070/how-find-a-n-if-the-sequence-a-n-2a-n-12n-12a-n-2-n-ge-1)

Comment: Since your sequence is recursively defined, I find impossible avoid induction. *This is not a short answer, but only a comment*.

Comment: ajotatxe is correct, math110. You need to take what you know about $a_n$ to prove something about $a_{n+1}$. That is essentially the definition of induction.

Comment: The very point is: what do you mean by: "find the $a_n$"? I would say this expands to "find an explicit $f(n)$ such that $\forall n : f(n) = a_n$". And this *has to be proven* with induction because you want to proof something for every natural number. This is also why "plugging in $a_n = 2n+1$" is not sufficient.

Comment: I corrected the formula in the title and made one slight change in your induction. I think your post is now correct.

Comment: Integers are defined using induction.  There is no such thing as proving a (nontrivial) statement about integers without using induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b_n = a_n - 2n$. Observe that $b_1 = 1$. We can substitute this into the given recurrence relation and get $$b_{n+1} + 2n = (b_n + 2n)\cdot b_n$$ In particular, this formula tells us: if for any $n$ we have $b_n = 1$, then $b_{n+1} = b_n$. Since $b_1 = 1$, it follows the sequence $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is constant. Hence $a_n = 2n + b_n = 2n + 1$.

Comment: While nice, this still uses an inductive argument.

Comment: it is very nice! +1

Answer (score 1):

What you want to prove is:

$\forall n \in\mathbb{N}: a_n = 2n+1$.

Of course, one can convince oneself that this equation holds by several ways, e.g. by *heuristics*, by *plugging in $2n+1$* into the recursive description or by *arguing that some sequence is constant*. But in every case one states that some property has to hold for every natural number (and this is obvious since the very claim you want to prove is a claim "for every natural number...").

For me, the most "induction hiding" version is "plugging in $2n+1$ into the recursive description". So I'll take this as an example where induction is hidden:

A proof could look like this:

### An example

We have $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - 2na_n +2$ for $n\geq 1$. Then $a_n = 2n+1$ since if we substitute:

$$\begin{aligned}
a_{n+1} &= (2n+1)^2 -2n(2n+1)+2\\&=4n^2+4n+1+2-4n^2-2n\\&=2n+3\\&=2(n+1)+1
\end{aligned}$$

it works.

Now, in fact, what have we proven? We have proven that:

$$\text{If $a_n = 2n+1$ (for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$) then $a_{n+1} = 2(n+1)+1$ (for this very $n$).}$$

Aha! This is the **induction step**. But still not the claim in question -- although almost.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the first several values of $a_n$ and look at the differences:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 &   & 5 &   & 7 &   & 9 \\
          & 2 &   & 2 &   & 2 &\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

The difference seems to always be $2$. This leads you to believe that the sequence is linear with the linear coefficient $2$. Finding that the constant term is $1$ then easy.

To check that this heuristically-derived answer is correct, substitute $a_n=2n+1$ into your recursion formula and see that it works.

Mathematical induction is often replaced by heuristics: see the book *How to Solve It* by George Polya for examples and details. Checking by substitution is a full and formal proof that the derived formula is correct. However, it does not prove that it is the *only* correct formula. Intuition tells us there is only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a candidate solution you can just do this:

1. Verify that $a_{n}=2n+1$ is a solution of the equation.
   This is simple algebra. No induction.
2. Argue that there can be only one solution for the equation, since it is deterministic:
   Given $a_0$, the value of all $a_n$ follow.

Comment: As I've stated above, your first point has to be proven by induction. Within the induction step *this is simple algebra* but the very claim is something like $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n = ...$.

Comment: That, plus checking that a_1 satisfies the condition _is_ induction.